# I want to use this cursor in SSIS Script Task, Using C# until all the records are parsed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

```
DECLARE @Line1 VARCHAR (MAX) 
DECLARE @Con_Line1 VARCHAR (MAX) 
DECLARE Pointer CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT TOP 13 Lines 
  FROM   dbo.Stage_Trdrev_TD 

OPEN Pointer 

FETCH NEXT FROM Pointer INTO @Line1 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      SET @Con_Line1 = ISNULL(@Con_Line1, ''+'01') 
                       + ISNULL (SUBSTRING(@Line1, 3, 101) + ' ', '') 

      FETCH NEXT FROM Pointer INTO @Line1 
  END 

SELECT LEFT(@Con_Line1, LEN(@Con_Line1) - 1) AS [Line] 

INSERT INTO Parse_Date_TD 
VALUES      (@Con_Line1) 

CLOSE Pointer 

DEALLOCATE Pointer

WITH D 
     AS (SELECT TOP 13 * 
         FROM   dbo.[Stage_Trdrev_TD]) 
DELETE FROM D
```

I want to use this cursor to parse the records from a table which has only one column and one record is consist of 13 line. I use this above cursor to manually but now I want it to run from ssis script task. until all the records are parsed.

Thank you...

Comment: Please format your code and explain your problem and consider shortening the title

Comment: Without an `ORDER  BY` you know that is an arbitrary set of 13 records, and in all possibility the 13 you delete afterwards aren't the 13 you operated on. Why don't you do some investigation on using a script transformation and post some skeleton code. Lastly.... why do you want to convert it? Is something wrong with this code? There are many good reasons to leave database code in the database.

Comment: I tested these codes and it working fine. The reason to convert to script is to use it in ssis package because i want it to run until all the records are parsed and there can be n number of records and i don't want it to run manually.

Comment: @ElectricLlama is correct - top is arbitrary without an ORDER BY clause.  You might get lucky in test, but there is no guarantee with each execution.  As for your execution of this, use an Execute SQL task, which was intended to execute database code inside an ssis package.

Comment: @ElectricLlama- Thanks for your advice i converted it into store proc and its working the way i wanted it to be. Thanks for the Idea!!!!!

Comment: I strongly advise you add an `ORDER BY`. Otherwise this will break when you least expect it and cause havoc. What will happen when you randomly delete incorrect records in this case? Even worse - what happens if someone inserts records in the middle of your process.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to make this into a Script (task or component)

What are you doing? You are deleting the top 13 rows from a table and concatenating the results together to shove into another table. This has been covered to death on SO.

Add an Execute SQL Task to your SSIS package.

Here's my table setup

```
CREATE TABLE 
    dbo.Stage_Trdrev_TD
(
    Lines varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE 
    dbo.Parse_Date_TD 
(
    Lines varchar(8000)
);

INSERT INTO 
    dbo.Stage_Trdrev_TD
SELECT
    V.name
FROM
    master.dbo.spt_values AS V;
```

This is the actual work. I create a temporary table to hold my deleted rows. Those deleted rows get concatenated into a single row which I then shove into the parsed table.

```
------------------
-- Now the "magic"
-------------

DECLARE
    @tbl TABLE
(
    lines varchar(100)
);

-- Tops without order is nuts
DELETE TOP (13) S
OUTPUT 
    DELETED.lines
INTO
    @tbl
FROM 
    dbo.Stage_Trdrev_TD AS S

-- Show the data before
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl T


-- Show what's about to go in
SELECT DISTINCT 
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' + T.lines
            FROM 
                @tbl Ti
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    ) AS ConcatenatedLines

FROM 
    @tbl T

-- Actually put it in

INSERT INTO
    dbo.Parse_Date_TD
SELECT DISTINCT 
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' + T.lines
            FROM 
                @tbl Ti
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    ) AS ConcatenatedLines

FROM 
    @tbl T;
```

Note, if you have NULLs in your source data, you're going to get bad results.